# How to make header appear on every screen in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

It looks like the header works only for stack navigator by default. I wonder **how to show headers for any screen opened from the navigator?**

Code that I have for the main screen

```
const createHomeStack = () =>
<Stack.Navigator>
 <Stack.Screen
  name='Feed'
  component={Feed}
 />
 <Stack.Screen name='Details' component={Details} />
 </Stack.Navigator>

const createBottomTabs = () =>
 <MaterialBottomTabs.Navigator>
  <MaterialBottomTabs.Screen name='Decks' component={Decks} />
  <MaterialBottomTabs.Screen name='Study' component={Study} />
 </MaterialBottomTabs.Navigator >

export default function App() {


 return (
 <Provider store={store}>
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' children={createHomeStack}
          options={{
            title: 'My home',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Translate' component={TranslateScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='History' component={History} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Study' component={createBottomTabs} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>
 );
 }
```

I am going for something that looks like the screenshot with the header present with the open or closed navigator on every screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look to [React-native-elements-header](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/header.html),

I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the solution, however did not find any nice way to wrap up every component automatically with custom header. So I ended up creating HOC component and wrapping each component for every screen.

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

const NavHeader = props => {
 // ... NavHeader code goes here 
};

export const withHeader = Component => {
  return props => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <NavHeader {...props} />
        <Component {...props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
};
```

Then in your Drawer you do:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
      component={withHeader(DashboardContainer)} // <--- Wrap it around component here.
    />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

This should also show that header for any nested components. In case you use StackNavigator you need to pass `options={{headerShown: false}}` to your `Screen.options`